# After recursive function returned true/false java continues to "return false" line that I put just to eliminite error

Tags: java, recursion

array a is a permutation of array b if both contain exactly the same numbers so:

```
a{ 3, 2, 4, 1, 5 } is permutation of b{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
```

I wrote this code:

```
int x4a[] = { 3, 2, 4, 1, 5 };
int x4b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
System.out.println(isPermutation(x4a, x4b));//Should return true

public static boolean isPermutation(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return isPermutation(a, b, 0, 0);
}

public static boolean isPermutation(int[] a, int[] b, int indexA, int indexB) {
    
    // This code will return true if the shorter array contains all the members of
    // the longer array.

    // In this case b will be compared to a
    if (a.length < b.length) {
        if (indexB == b.length - 1 && a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return true;
        else if (a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            isPermutation(a, b, 0, indexB + 1);
        else if (indexA == a.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return false;
        else if (indexA < a.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            isPermutation(a, b, indexA + 1, indexB);

    } else {
        if (indexA == a.length - 1 && a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return true;
        else if (a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            isPermutation(a, b, 0, indexA + 1);
        else if (indexB == b.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return false;
        else if (indexB < b.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            isPermutation(a, b, indexA, indexB + 1);
    }
    // DEAFAULT to eliminate the error
    return false;
}
```

This return false despite it should return true.
When I run in the debugger it shows me that the recursion goes deeper successfully but when it gets out it runs through the last line which returns false.
I have tried to do boolean variable and return that but that gave me a run error.

Is there any way to avoid writing the last line or any other way to solve this?

Comment: You should return the result of `isPermutation` when you call it recursively, otherwise what are you calling it for?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I do, my if statements don't give any other choice but to return either true or false.

Comment: You don't. Not in all cases, at least. That's the reason you had to add that `return false` at the end. What I mean is that all those call to `isPermutation(........);` should probably be `return isPermutation(.......);`, otherwise you're just ignoring whatever the recursive call returned and you fall through to that `return false`.

Comment: For example suppose `a.length < b.length` and `a[indexA] == b[indexB]` (i.e. the first `else if`). What are you returning in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just prepend return with every isPermutation call so that the last line does not execute.

```
if (a.length < b.length) {
        if (indexB == b.length - 1 && a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return true;
        else if (a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return isPermutation(a, b, 0, indexB + 1);
        else if (indexA == a.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return false;
        else if (indexA < a.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return isPermutation(a, b, indexA + 1, indexB);

    } else {
        if (indexA == a.length - 1 && a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return true;
        else if (a[indexA] == b[indexB])
            return isPermutation(a, b, 0, indexA + 1);
        else if (indexB == b.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return false;
        else if (indexB < b.length - 1 && a[indexA] != b[indexB])
            return isPermutation(a, b, indexA, indexB + 1);
    }
    // DEAFAULT to eliminate the error
    return false;
```